# Equal margins/border-radius in mobile web app using CSS without pixel value

Tags: html, css, mobile

Sorry for the confusing title. Hard to describe. I'm making a mobile web app using HTML, JS and CSS. Of course, it will be used on many different sized devices. I'm trying to keep the margins (i.e. the space around the outside of the div, not `margin: ...`) of this div consistent all the way around. But using percentages makes the vertical and horizontal margins different, depending on the element's size.

```
#selector {
   position: absolute;
   top: 5%;
   bottom: 5%;
   left: 5%;
   right: 5%;
   background: white;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   border-radius: 2%;
   border: 2px solid red;
}
```

So, basically, I want the space around the outside this absolute positioned div to be equal all the way around, no matter the size of the window. Is there a way to do this using pure CSS and without using pixels (b/c device screen resolutions vary greatly). I am also looking for a similar solution for border-radius without using a pixel value in the CSS.

Comment: You can use em it's not as good as using percent but its better than using pixles

Comment: The problem with using em and percentage, is that since the height of the screen is greater than the width the space at the bottom and top will not be equal to the space at the sides. I'm looking for equal spacing all around.

Comment: Are you willing to use js, jquery, or jquery mobile?

Comment: Yes, but I would prefer not to, if possible.

Comment: I assume by that response you know how to via one of those methods?

Comment: Yes. But, I was hoping I could find an easier way. But I could have had it done by now, after all this time posting this question :-).

Comment: Yeah, as far as I know theres no easy way to do top bottom with % since it is dependent on the container. The only way it would work is if you hard set something...